# GXT Login with an User Bean Model

Tags: gxt, javabeans

is it possible to create a login with gxt using a user bean model? I am totally new to gxt.

Best regards,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I have done it both in GlassFish and Google AppEngine.